# How to write a static file server in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, webserver

(I've read the tutorial on nodeBeginner.com, and that's about Node.) It's really nice to have an example of file server which contains basic concept of how POST method was used for beginners. I've read some introductions about the Clojure language, but is there any nice guide about writing server?

Answer (score 0):

Check out various clojure web frameworks at this [link](http://www.infoq.com/news/2011/10/clojure-web-frameworks).

NOTE: The server part will be actually existing Java web servers like jetty,netty. The application logic will be implemented using any of the frameworks mentioned in the above link.

Answer (score 0):

This one on Compojure seems to cover what you need:

http://cleancode.se/2010/08/30/getting-started-with-compojure.html